# Find issues with at least one label on GitHub

Tags: github

How do I find any GitHub issue which has at least one label on it?

Just like we can filter out unlabeled issues on GitHub, is there a way to find only labeled (it can be any label) issues?

Comment: Seems like `-no:label` should do the trick, but it does not seem to.